# Adding an external switch and external LEDs to this circuit

Tags: circuit-design, soldering, wiring

I'm building an arcade cabinet, and would like to incorporate two different gaming systems (PC and a FPGA).  I have the overall setup functioning (PC + FPGA --> KVM with external switch --> CRT screen).

This KVM, pictured below, runs off a 5 V USB power source, and has an external push-button switch connected to it via a mini-USB cable.

[image: Picture of KVM below - external switch goes into the "Wired Remote" mini-USB port]

The external switch has (what appears to be) a basic PCB with two LEDs (signifying which device the output is receiving from), controlled by a momentary micro-switch on the board:

[image: Front of switch]

[image: back of switch]

It also alternates which LED lights up (corresponding to the input selected).

What I want to do:

Bypass the microswitch and LEDs on this board (or remove them) and connect an external momentary switch to it, which would be located on the outside of the Arcade cabinet. I'd also like to wire the LED outputs to the outside of the cabinet (where the LEDs would light-up next to the name of the system I've selected).

1. I'm very new to circuits. I understand the basic concepts of current, voltage, resistance, etc., and have *some* familiarity with switches in general.
2. I've soldered exactly once (attached a loose wire to battery case). I do have a soldering iron.
3. I have a multimeter (if that helps).
4. I'm willing to invest in tools/supplies (desoldering station?) as long as it's not overboard. If so, I'd appreciate specific recommendations if you have any.

Is this possible, and if so, could one of you kind folks direct me on how to approach it?

Comment: If you twist the cables between the board and wherever external place you move the switch and LEDs to, I don’t see any issues why it wouldn’t work. Perhaps even a shielded TP cable between the board and where you have the switches?

Comment: Or drill three holes in the cabinet for the LEDs and button, and mount that board itself.  Could use new LEDs with longer legs and fashion an extension for the button (perhaps 3D print or get a friend to 3D print.)

Comment: Desoldering is harder than soldering, it is easy to damage the board. Be careful, or your next post will be how to repair a PWB. For through-hole parts, it is often easier if you are willing to sacrifice the existing part (cut the leads on top, then you can unsolder the leads one at a time). You may be able to do this for the LEDs, probably not the switch. For the switch, assuming it is a simple normally-open configuration, consider leaving the switch on the PWB and wiring the new switch in parallel.

Comment: Thank you all.  Fortunately, worst-case-scenario, I have a back-up for the remote-control (and another replacement, if needed, isn't prohibitively expensive).  I do like the idea of removing the LED's (cutting them off from the top, de-soldering from the bottom), and wiring the switch in parallel.  As I'm very much a novice to all of this, I'm going to clarify some assumptions:   1) LED's come in different voltage/resistance, and I should test these before I cut them off, so I know what to replace with 2) Use multimeter to see which two solder joints of the switch are actually the circuit?

Comment: LEDs are polarized, they only light when the current is in the proper direction. If you can, measure the voltage on the LEDs before you remove anything. Be sure to note the direction. I see a plus sign near the LEDs, but it is nice to confirm. Simple LEDs like this rarely have resistors inside them, just get the same physical size and color and it should work.

Comment: Use an ohmeter to find the 2 active pins of the switch. Two of the pins may be non-functional, or the pins may be wired in pairs. Always have power off when using an ohmmeter.

Comment: A desoldering station is way overkill for hobbyist purposes, these are expensive. You can desolder with a solder wick braid, though it takes a bit of skill/experience not to muck up the pads/vias. The classic mistake is to not heat it properly so that the braid gets stuck to the joint, and that's when things break. Practice using one on some junk board first.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a simple project since you are just making the wires longer - no real electrical changes.

---

## Switch

If you look closely at the PCB you can see the switch has four pins metal pins going into the PCB, but the top two and the bottom two are connected together on the PCB. Only two pins are needed for a switch, but this type of switch has extra pins, just to make sure the switch is tightly soldered the board and doesn't bend when you press it. The top two work the same, and the bottom two work the same - you can use either. (Top and bottom relative to the pictures you showed)

You can attach your own switch in parallel with this switch and they will both work. Strip the ends of two wires, and solder one to the top and one to the bottom. You can use the front or back side of the PCB, you can use either the left or right, but it does have to be one wire on one of the top pins, and one wire on one of the bottom pins.

Then attach the other ends of the wires to the button that goes on the cabinet. The way to do that would depend on the button you choose. Probably more soldering.

---

## LEDs

It's the same, except the LED only has two pins and the only soldering point is on the back - unless you cut the LED off the front. LEDs don't work as nicely in parallel as switches do (see below) so you might choose to remove the LEDs from the PCB.

You might be able to get underneath the LEDs with wire cutters and snip each pin (there are 2). Alternatively, bend it back and forth until the pins break from metal fatigue. If there's not enough room for either of those, and you don't want to desolder, you might try to crush it with pliers until it shatters (wear safety glasses), but ya know, that could make life more difficult instead of less, so it's up to you. Otherwise, just leave it in place and see below.

If you do want to desolder, you'll need one of those solder sucker thingies or copper wick that absorbs solder, and a vise or other holder to hold the PCB for you. Put a big blob of solder across both the pads on the back (as they're right next to each other) and keep your iron on that blob, so the solder stays molten, while you pull out the LED with pliers (or if you're lucky it may just fall out by itself). Keep in mind the existing solder is probably lead-free solder so it will need a higher temperature than normal. Once the LED is out, use the solder sucker or wick to remove the excess solder (while it's molten) so the solder isn't connecting the pads together.

If you connect two LEDs in parallel, only the one with the longer wavelength will end up working. So red+green -> red one works. Green+blue -> green one works. White counts the same as blue. Green+green -> who knows? might be either one due to manufacturing variations, or an unpredictable mixture of both (one bright, one dim). So if you leave the existing LEDs on the board then try to use a longer-wavelength colour on the cabinet. Hopefully the ones on the board aren't red. Looks like they are white, but sometimes the plastic colour isn't the same colour the LED actually lights up. If you do remove the existing LEDs, this problem won't apply.

Also, it matters which way around you connect the LEDs. If you connect them backwards, they simply won't work. Luckily, the PCB has a big + written on one side of each LED. So unless they're being real sneaky, you know that side is +. And on the LEDs you buy for your cabinet, there should also be a way to tell which side is +. On the traditional round LEDs (like the ones on the PCB) the + pin is longer, and the round part has a flat spot next to the - pin.

If you want to be really sure, you could use the multimeter to test the voltage across the two LED pins when the LED is on. But I wouldn't bother. It's reasonable to assume the side labelled + is really +.

---

## Soldering the wires to the new parts

Should be pretty straightforward - except that you'll need something to hold both the wire and the part in place while you solder it. Sometimes parts come with tabs with holes and you can hook the wire through the tab so it doesn't fall off. Other times you just have two bare wires to solder and then you definitely need a way to hold them.

I bring it up here to mention - *use heatshrink*. Slide it onto the wire (a good distance back from the solder joint), do the soldering, then slide the heatshrink over the solder joint and shrink it. Some people use a cigarette lighter, but I found that you can also just hold your soldering iron underneath and the hot air will be enough to make it shrink. Using heatshrink to insulate the connection prevents it from accidentally touching another connection and short-circuiting when you move the cabinet, which would be annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for sharing your knowledge and experience.  I did end up getting a desoldering station, and it ended up working out.  I found some PCB mount screw terminals on amazon.com, which ended up being very handy to connect the external components to.

The terminal that replaced the 4-pin button was a bit trickier - the circuit appeared to only connect the top two pins, but in practice, I had to short one of the top pins with one of the bottom pins in order for the switch to activate.  Ended up figuring it out through trial and error. You can't really tell from the photo, but connected one wire from the blue terminal on the PCB to my push-button switch, and soldered the other switch wire to one of the bottom pins on the PCB).

I think it turned out ok for my 1st real "project".

Thanks again!:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Very nice. Side note you could have recreated this entire board on a simple breadboard/strip board and a few parts, and a spare old usb mini cable.

Comment: Thank you.  I was wondering about that.  I wasn't sure what the pair of small transistor-looking things (The ones inside the rectangles that are marked "01" and "02" respectively) were for, so figured I'd make few changes.

Comment: Those are transistors. Labeled Q1 and Q2. Q is the designator for transistor like R is for resistor and D for diode. Q2 has r5 has its base transistor and is likely a npn type in common emitter setup to turn the right led on. I don't see a base resistor for q1, it could be an pnp setup so they could use one signal to turn the leds on/off in alternating fashion.